# Barba.js - Update URL if a PHP redirect has occured

Tags: redirect, barbajs

I've got some dead pages in my site that I just need to redirect.

Thing is, if you click on a link where it goes to one of these redirected pages, the redirection will occur, but the URL will be kept as the old, dead page.

Example: I click on a page /a/ that PHP redirects to /b/. The redirection happens, /b/ is shown, but the URL stays /a/ until I would hard refresh (CTRL+R) the page.

So is there a way to make it so Barba follows PHP redirects and updates the URL to show the right one?